# Running Google Assistant SDK on Android 4.0?

Tags: android, google-assistant-sdk

I cannot find anywhere what level of Android the Google Assistants SDK requires. Can you run it on Android 4.0+?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Google Assistant SDK](https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/) is meant to be embedded in devices you build. While you can embed it in an Android Things device (which is based on Android 8.0 Oreo), it can also be used on any device/OS that can send and receive an audio stream.

Perhaps you are asking about [developing an Action](https://developers.google.com/actions/) that can be run under the Google Assistant?

Comment: Yes, I think this should be it. I tried running samples but every sample needed Android 21+ API and I thought I cannot embed it into lower systems. Thank you!